# jQuery click function firing at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two click functions that seem to be firing at the same time. I need the second to only happen after the first.

So the first slideDown is working fine but once that has finished I want it to stop, and then the slideUp to happen own the .close class is clicked.

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(".mobileWrap").slideDown(500);
    $(".mainContentBg").addClass("height", 1000);
    $(".trigger").text("Read less");
    $(".trigger").addClass("close");
    $(".close").removeClass("trigger");
});
$("body").on("click", ".close", function() {
    $(".mainContentBg").removeClass("height", 1000);
    $(".mobileWrap").slideUp(1000);
    $(".trigger").addClass("trigger");
    $(".trigger").text("Read more");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6hvZT/648/

Thanks

Comment: You must stop the click event form bubbling up to the body click event

Comment: `addClass` doesn't expect a second argument

Comment: @haim770 it can if you're using jQueryUI: http://api.jqueryui.com/addclass/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, The question isn't tagged jQueryUI, but didn't know that anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code :

As the class `close` is being added, the delegated click is being triggered.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hvZT/651/)**

If your wish is to toggle `More-Less`;You can just use `toggleClass` and `slideToggle` instead of two different click events,slideUp/slideDown and addClass/removeClass.

Below is the shortened code.

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(".mobileWrap").slideToggle(500);
    $(".mainContentBg").toggleClass("height", 1000);
    $(".trigger").text(function(){
        return this.innerText === "Read less"? "Read more":"Read less"
    });
});
```

Also, if you have multiple such instances, inside the handler it is better to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.trigger')`